# Application in Docker container binds UDP to random port

Tags: docker, networking, udp, port

I'm attempting to run an application in Docker that talks to a server. The client opens and binds a UDP socket with port 0, so the port number is just a random available port. It then communicates with the server and reports what port the client is listening. On a Linux host, this works fine because of the --net=host option when running the container. However, this is not available in Windows using WSL2.  The port must be published when the container starts, but I don't what it is until the application starts and binds the socket.

Do I have to force a bind to a known port?  If I have more than one client on machine, the second one's bind will result in an "address already in use" failure.

I've also thought that I can restrict the net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range to something like 30000-30100 and publish this ports, but that seems pretty hacky.

I also tried publishing something like 20000 ports, but that hung the docker run command. It also didn't seem like a very good idea.

Comment: Will it be an option to pass a port using the docker environment viriable at container start and make the app run on that port? So you could also publish a desired port and map in to the specified one previously